# what is 'NameError: name 'R' is not defined' error and how can we rectify it?

Tags: python

NameError: name 'R' is not defined
I tried alot to rectify it but to no use

```
g=int(input('ENTER THE NUMBER:  '))
while (g!=0):
  r=g%10
  R=R*10+r
  n/=10
if(R==n):
  print("It is a Palindrome",g)
else:
  print("It is not A Palindrome",g)    
print("Reversed Number ",R)
```

Comment: `R` uses `R` in its definition. What happens on the first iteration of the `while` loop?

Comment: Start your program by initializing `R` to zero. It doesn't exist until you do, so the `R` in  `R*10+r` doesn't exist the first time through your loop. That is the `NameError`. You appear to expect previously undefined variables to have the value zero. Not in Python. And `n/=10` should be `n //= 10` because you need integer division, not floating point division.

Comment: `g=int(input('ENTER THE NUMBER:  '))

  while (g!=0):
      R=0
      r=g%10
      R=R*10+r
      g/=10
  if(R==g):
      print("It is a Palindrome",g)
  else:
      print("It is not A Palindrome",g)    
  print("Reversed Number ",R)`
i re wrote the code like this but to no change  

the out i got is like this

ENTER THE NUMBER:  141
It is not A Palindrome 0
Reversed Number  1